# Axios Post return 405 Method Not Allowed on Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, iis, .net-core, axios, asp.net-core-5.0

I'm trying to made a POST request on a NET CORE 5 service (hosted on IIS 10) from a Vue.js app with axios.

When I test the service with POSTMAN it's working perfectly but with Axios I'm always getting a 405 from the server.

Analyzing the requests with fiddler are looking very different. IN the axios request the content-type header is missing and the method is OPTIONS instead of POST.

This is the POSTMAN request:

```
POST https://localhost/apiluxor/api/SignIn HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.28.4
Accept: */*
Postman-Token: acfed43c-731b-437b-a88a-e640e8216032
Host: localhost
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 55

{
    "username":"user",
    "password":"testpw"
}
```

And this is the axios request:

```
OPTIONS https://localhost/apiluxor/api/SignIn HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: */*
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type
Origin: http://172.16.1.110:8080
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/95.0.4638.54 Safari/537.36
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Referer: http://172.16.1.110:8080/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: it-IT,it;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
```

In my Vue.js module I've tried to force the settings of the 'content-type' in the main config and in the post request with no results.

```
import { App } from "vue";
import axios from "axios";
import VueAxios from "vue-axios";
import JwtService from "@/core/services/JwtService";
import { AxiosResponse, AxiosRequestConfig } from "axios";

class ApiService {
  public static vueInstance: App;
  public static init(app: App<Element>) {
    ApiService.vueInstance = app;
    ApiService.vueInstance.use(VueAxios, axios);
    ApiService.vueInstance.axios.defaults.baseURL =
      "https://localhost/apiluxor/api";
    ApiService.vueInstance.axios.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] =
      "application/json";
  }

  public static setHeader(): void {
    ApiService.vueInstance.axios.defaults.headers.common[
      "Authorization"
    ] = `Bearer ${JwtService.getToken()}`;
  }

  public static post(
    resource: string,
    params: AxiosRequestConfig
  ): Promise<AxiosResponse> {
    return ApiService.vueInstance.axios.post(resource, params, {
      headers: { "content-type": "application/json" },
    });
  }

export default ApiService;
```

I'm very new to Vue.js so maybe I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that axios made a CORS request before the POST, and the NET Core API should be configured to accept CORS request.

I've found an article ([here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/enable-cors-4-in-iis-10/)) that saying the problem for this cases is that IIS does not accept CORS request and the [CORS module](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/iis-cors-module) should be installed .
I've tried this change but the result was the I was receving an HTTP/1.1 204 No Content instead of a 403.

In my case the problem was the API service itself.

The CORS should be enabled in the API Service.
In NET CORE 5  for a basic configuration it's enough to add the CORS services in Startup

```
services.AddCors();
```

and configure it

```
    app.UseCors(builder =>
    {
        builder
        .AllowAnyOrigin()
        .AllowAnyMethod()
        .AllowAnyHeader();
    });
```

With these changes the service works perfectly for any vue.js requests coming from axios.

Comment: I'm so glad that the problem has been resolved. It is so appreciated if you can mark solution as answer.

Answer (score 0):

To send the data as JSON in the body of the post request, just add a parameter "data" to the axios options. Axios will automatically set the content-tpe to the proper value for you.

```js
// Simple example
axios.post(myUrl, {
  data: {
    "username":"user",
    "password":"testpw"
  }
});
```

This should have the expected outcome :)